# Difference between lazy val and def, if the function is guaranteed to be called only once?

Tags: scala, function, lazy-evaluation

I have the following two snippets:
Assume that `map` is a global map, `Int => Int`

```
def foobar(n: Int): Boolean = {
  val res = map.get(n)
  lazy val isEven = res.get % 2 == 0
  lazy val divides3 = res.get % 3 == 0

  res.isDefined && (isEven || divides3)
}
```

```
def foobar(n: Int): Boolean = {
  val res = map.get(n)
  def isEven = res.get % 2 == 0
  def divides3 = res.get % 3 == 0

  res.isDefined && (isEven || divides3)
}
```

Both achieve the same result, however, they are subtly different, `lazy val` is used instead of a `def`.
Will there be any changes in execution, memory, bytecodes or somewhere else?

Or are these exactly identical?

My gut is that if a `def` is used, it'll be treated differently that a `lazy val`, since that `def` *could* be called from somewhere else.

EDIT 1: "The function" in the title refers to the two internal functions, in the second example

Comment: `map` is not a good variable name in Scala. It is usually used as a function to map one value into another.

Comment: Agreed. This was more for demonstration purposes, specifically discussing the difference between `lazy val` and `def`

Answer (score 3):

`lazy val` ensures there is only a single evaluation. It accomplishes this through locking and status fields, and has a bit of a footprint.

Since it's only called once anyway, the `def` variety has less overhead.

If these kinds of performance optimizations matter for your application, you should always benchmark.

Also include the non-micro-optimized version

```
def foobar(n: Int) = map.get(n)
                        .map(r => r % 2 == 0 || r % 3 == 0)
                        .getOrElse(false)
```

Comment: But the `def` would be encoded as another private method on the object, thus increasing jar size. But I believe the `lazy val` is encoded as its own class with the locks, so maybe even a greater jar size... man performance is hard.

Comment: An even better non-micro-optimized version would be `map.get(_).filter(r => r % 2 || r % 3).isDefined`

Comment: `map.get(n).exists(r => r % 2 == 0 || r % 3 == 0)`

Comment: For the OP: as always, check the generated bytecode for both versions.

Comment: @LeviRamsey yes, and also don't make too many assumptions about the performance profile of the bytecode without benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks all for the response. The snippet provided was only to show the usage, and not some actual code I'm trying to optimize.   Just wanted to know the technical differences between the two.

Comment: @HariKrishnan if you need to squeeze the last drop of performance out of things, you will just have to make sure you benchmark and compile with proper optimizing flags. The devil tends to be in the details. Suitable microoptimizations for one program may slow down another.